# How to remove all selected character from any strings which is not at first position

Tags: mysql, regex, regexp-replace

How can I remove all the "A" from any character string **(except of the "A" located at the beginning position of same string)** through the regular expression in MySQL ?

For example I have a column "MemberName" containing string "ANSHUMAN" and many more names like that. I want to know how can I remove all the "A" except of "A" situated at starting position from string "ANSHUMAN".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following solution using [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace):

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(column_name, '[A]+', '', 2)
FROM table_name
```

The fourth parameter of `REGEXP_REPLACE` defines the starting position of the search.

---

Another solution without using regular expression (in case MySQL version doesn't support):

```
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(column_name, 1), REPLACE(SUBSTR(column_name, 2), 'A', ''))
FROM table_name
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=554313d6b20ca9531af2a936c662e9a6)